# Порядок элементов в структуре со встраиваемым типом в Go

Tags: golang

Есть такой код Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type AliasPhone Phone
type Phone struct {
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
}
type Phones []Phone

func main() {
    const jsonStream = `[{"type":"Домашний","number":false,"status":"Не подключен"},{"type":"Сотовый","number":"+79990000000","status":"Не отвечает"},{"type":"Рабочий","number":"70000","status":"Доступен"}]`
    fmt.Println(jsonStream)
    var p Phones
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStream), &p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(p)

    r, err := json.Marshal(p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(r))

    var p2 Phones
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(r), &p2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(p2)

    if equal(p, p2) {
        fmt.Println("Структуры до и после Unmarshal равны")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Структуры до и после Unmarshal не равны")
    }

    if jsonStream == string(r) {
        fmt.Println("Json`ы равны ")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Json`ы не равны ")
    }

}

func (ph Phone) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return ph.marshalJSON()
}

func (ph Phone) marshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    phStr := AliasPhone(ph)
    if ph.Number != "Нет" {
        return json.Marshal(phStr)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            *AliasPhone
            Number bool `json:"number"`
        }{
            AliasPhone: (*AliasPhone)(&ph),
            Number:     false,
        })
    }
}

func (ph *Phone) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return unmarshalPhone(data, ph)
}
func unmarshalPhone(data []byte, phone *Phone) error {
    //Если в номере телефона (Number) строка, то просто делаем Unmarshal
    phStr := (*AliasPhone)(phone)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &phStr); err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    //Если в номере телефона (Number) false
    phBool := &struct {
        Number bool `json:"number"`
        *AliasPhone
    }{
        AliasPhone: (*AliasPhone)(phone),
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &phBool); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    phone.Number = "Нет"
    return nil
}

func equal(x, y Phones) bool {
    if len(x) != len(y) {
        return false
    }
    for i := range x {
        if x[i] != y[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pYzG_TdRmZ

В коде есть структура Phones с срезом структур Phone. В этот срез нужно записать Unmarshal от jsonStream. А потом обратно. Так как в number кроме строк, бывает false, то пришлось написать свои Marshal и Unmarshal.

Проблема в том, что анонимной структуре в marshalJSON(), поле Number следует за включаемой структурой-синонимом AliasPhone. И значит, что поле Number идет в конце.

Мне нужно, что бы в json`е после Marshal порядок следования полей был такой же как и в jsonStream, то-есть поле Number было между Type и Status.

Такое можно как-то сделать?
Заранее благодарю, за любой совет!

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**
Думал еще сделать так, но это костыль, надо как-то по-другому:

```
func (ph Phone) marshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    phStr := AliasPhone(ph)
    if ph.Number != "Нет" {
        return json.Marshal(phStr)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            *AliasPhone
            Number bool   `json:"number"`
            Status string `json:"status"`
        }{
            AliasPhone: (*AliasPhone)(&ph),
            Number:     false,
            Status:     ph.Status,
        })
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LmUvL_s_6e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нашел ответа как подобное сделать и решил немного переписать тесты. 
Просто стал JSON сравнивать не строками, а так:

```
func JSONEqual(a, b []byte) (bool, error) {
    var j, j2 interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(a, &j); err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &j2); err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return reflect.DeepEqual(j2, j), nil
}
```